# Get TextField identity in tableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, uitextfield

In my app I use textFields in tableView. But When user click to the text field in the second cell I need to add one mor cell to table view (like mail.app), but how can I get number of cell, if i click to the text field?

I tried so

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{
    //some action
}
```

but this function didn't start when I click to the textField inside the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the text field inside your table view cell, set your view controller (or whatever you want) to conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and set it as the text field delegate.

Then, set the text field **TAG** property to equal the row number for the table view cell.

When the user clicks on the text field, you'll get a delegate message sent to your [`textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldBeginEditing%3a) method and you'll know the cell's row number because you stored it in the tag property.

I hope my answer helps you out!

Comment: I change the declaration of my class as @interface UYLModalViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate> and write - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"dsad");
} But in debug mode I didn't came to this function. What I hevae missed?

Comment: You need to make sure to set your text field delegate to your `UYLModalViewController`.  Once you do that, the delegate method should get called.

Comment: How can I do It. I add its dynamicaly.

Comment: if you add it dynamically from within your `UYLModalViewController`, wherever you create & add the `UITextField` to the table view cell, just set the delegate for that newly created text field to `self` (which points it to your view controller).

Comment: I write so    l_textField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:TextFieldFrame];
    l_textField.tag = cellRow;
   l_textField.delegate = self; but I take a warning "Assigning to id<UITExtFieldDelegate> from incompatible type UIModalViewController", and it hasn't go to delegate method =( May be I write something wrong?

Comment: Oh, I find a mistake, a write  l_textField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:TextFieldFrame], but need UITextView. Your solution is correct) thabks a lot!

Comment: I can not get text field tag in textFieldShouldBeginEditing: method, this return nil when called textfield.tag

Comment: @kemdo this sounds like a new / different question to me... [`tag`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag?language=objc) (which `UITextField` inherits from `UIView`) is an `Int`-eger, which means it simply ***cannot*** be nil like a typical Objective-C object. It can be `0` by default.  Try posting a new question and I'll take a look at it with you (and everyone else trying to get points).